# Type of Replacement Switch For Auto Dimming Outdoor Security Light

Tags: switch

I have an existing security light mounted on my garage, with two floodlight bulbs, that comes on at dusk.  The light is generally on in a dimming mode all night, unless the motion detector senses a presence.  This light can be operated from a switch (that has an anti-kid tampering lock on it) located in the house.  I believe the switch is in need of replacement.  What type of switch is used for this... single pole, three way, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

### Exactly the switch you already have.

You look at your wiring -- and in doing so you ignore ground wires (which are green typically).  Ground is connected everywhere, but it doesn't participate in the normal wiring, so we don't talk about it.   If you see

- If the switch has 2 screws (again ignoring ground screws/wires), it's a **plain switch**.
- If the switch has 2 **brass** and 1 **black** screw, it's a **common 3-way**.
- If the switch has 2 **brass** and 2 **black** screws, it's a 4-way middle switch.
- If the switch doesn't have screws but has pigtails instead, it's a dimmer, smart switch, motion sensor, that kind of thing. Snap us photos of anything distinctive and edit your post to include them.

With 3/4 way switches, which screw is on brass vs. black is **very important**.  The physical position of the screws is useless and misleading (since every switch puts them in different places!!)  Also, wire color is useless and misleading - the screws they go to are the key.